# Retry individual action error of logstash-output-elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using **twitter-input** to fetch data from twitter and **ouput-Elasticsearch** to store it in elasticsearch
and I am using Logstash 5.2.1 in Ubuntu OS when I run it through the following error

```
[2017-03-02T08:18:45,576][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Retrying individual actions
[2017-03-02T08:18:45,576][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Action
[2017-03-02T08:18:50,796][INFO][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 503 ({"type"=>"unavailable_shards_exception", "reason"=>"[twitter_news][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest to [twitter_news] containing [1] requests]"})
[2017-03-02T08:18:50,796][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Retrying individual actions
[2017-03-02T08:18:50,796][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Action
[2017-03-02T08:18:55,840][INFO][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] retrying failed action with response code: 503 ({"type"=>"unavailable_shards_exception", "reason"=>"[twitter_news][0] primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m], request: [BulkShardRequest to [twitter_news] containing [1] requests]"})
[2017-03-02T08:18:55,840][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Retrying individual actions
[2017-03-02T08:18:55,841][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Action
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really anything we should've cared about in the first place. Nobody knows why they made that an error message...

Anyway, they [fixed it](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/564) and it's an information now.